# Did this character's illness have a non-terrestrial cause?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-love-and-thunder

In the film *Thor: Love and Thunder*,

> Jane Foster

is revealed to be suffering from a highly aggressive cancer that appeared very suddenly.

Notwithstanding that at least one of their parents also died of cancer at a similar age (which could indicate that there's some genetic propensity), is there any specific* confirmation of what caused this to occur?

*<sub>By specific, I mean something stated by someone involved in the making of the film. I've seen plenty of *[web speculation](https://wegotthiscovered.com/movies/what-caused-jane-foster-to-get-cancer-in-thor-love-and-thunder-here-are-our-theories/)* that it was a result of an Infinity Stone encounter or spending intimate time with a certain super-powered character, but I'm looking for something more definitive.</sub>

Comment: In technical parlance, I believe this is termed a "plot tumor."

Comment: Would any downvoters care to explain why they're downvoting? Too spoiler-y?

Comment: It's a well thought out question in my opinion.

Comment: "highly aggressive cancer that appeared very suddenly" - we haven't seen Jane since *Thor: The Dark World*, and the cancer could have appeared anytime between then and "six months" prior to the movie. She only was able to "find out" about it that six months prior, and it's possible for cancer to go undetected for years.

Comment: @PeterNielsen - "*I was just feeling tired. And then, they told me I have stage four [cancer]"*. That sounds quite rapid to me, but you're not wrong that it could have been developing for years

Comment: As someone who had cancer, sometimes we never know. It just shows up.

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question (since it's comics and they never really establish the cause), but in the comics, [the cancer happened before she got the hammer, and the effect of Mjollnir was essentially to eliminate the results of chemo since it was a "poison" to be removed from the body](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Jane_Foster_(Earth-616)#Death_of_the_Mighty_Thor).

Comment: FWIW, [there is a basis for Marvel characters getting cancer through sex with superhumans](https://screenrant.com/spider-man-kill-mary-jane-gross-radioavtive-sperm/).

Answer (score 5):

**It's most likely nothing more than genetics.**

In the movie, we see

> Jane flashback to her childhood, when another character, Elaine Foster (who is presumably Jane's mother) dying of cancer (not explicitly mentioned, but inferred) on a hospital bed.

We then see

> her gravestone.

More likely than not the cancer is hereditary due to mutations in genes passed along to Jane through Elaine. This is actually possible with cancer in real life. Therefore it's most likely a genetic cause to begin with, and *then*

> amplified by Mjölnir.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence from the makers to back this up, or is it just **your own guess based on the evidence I already pointed out**?

Comment: I'm looking, but I think inferentially this is the best answer you could get

Comment: Surprisingly there haven't been a lot of interviews with the creators recently.

Comment: I don't want inference. I've explicitly asked for evidence in the question